# How to pass argument through FCM to navigate to a screen? flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a cloud function to send message at a particular update. I am able to navigate to a particular screen by clicking on the notification. But I also want to pass userID as argument to that screen while navigating. My cloud function code is as below

```
exports.sendNotificationOnBooking = functions.firestore.document('Bookings/{docId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
var userId = snapshot.get("ownerID");
var booking_time =snapshot.get("noOfHours");
console.log("This is User Id:", userId);
const db = admin.firestore();
const profile = db.collection('Profiles').doc(userId);
const nameDoc = await profile.get();
var userName = '';
if (!nameDoc.exists) {
  console.log('UserName not Fetched');
}
else {
  userName = nameDoc.data()['name']
  console.log('username', userName);
}
const cityRef = db.collection('DeviceTokens').doc(userId);
const doc = await cityRef.get();
var userToken = '';
if (!doc.exists) {
  console.log('No such Document!!');
} else {
  userToken = doc.data()['token']
  console.log('User Token', userToken);
}
var payload = {
  "notification": {
    "title": "Booking alert",
    "body": `Your equipment has been booked for ${booking_time} hours`,
    
  },
  "data":{
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    "path":"/myBookingScreen",            
  },
};
try {
  const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userToken, payload);
  console.log("Notification sent Successfully");
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error ");
  console.log(error);
}
});
```

From this function when I try to print the payload I get only /myBookingScreen as result.
Here is my flutter code

```
 flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (route) async {
  if (route != null) {
    print(route.payload.toString());

    navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed("${route.payload}");
  }
});
```

I have referred few examples where they take the value like route["path"]. But that is not working for me. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To pass additional arguments while navigating to a particular screen from a notification, you can add them as query parameters in the path field of the notification payload.

For example, in your cloud function code, you can modify the payload object to include the `userID` as a query parameter:

```dart
var payload = {
  "notification": {
    "title": "Booking alert",
    "body": `Your equipment has been booked for ${booking_time} hours`,    
  },
  "data":{
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    "path":"/myBookingScreen?userID=${userId}",
  },
};
```

in your Flutter code, you can extract the query parameter value from the payload object and pass it to the target screen:

```dart
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (route) async {
        if (route != null) {
        print(route.payload.toString());

        final uri = Uri.parse("${route.payload}");
        final path = uri.path;
        final queryParams = uri.queryParameters;
        final userId = queryParams['userID'];

        navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(path, arguments: userId);
    }
});
```

This code extracts the `userID` query parameter value from the payload URI and passes it as an argument to the target screen using the arguments parameter of the pushNamed method.

Comment: I tried this. Its not working. route.payload print is empty

Comment: probably it is because of formatting, make sure the payload is formatted correctly.

Comment: if we give the path inside double quotes it is not taking userid as a variable. So I gave the path inside this symbol ` ` .